# How can I disable the Windows Dictation pop-up?

Tags: windows-10

When I press the Win + H keys on my keyboard in Windows 10, I get a popup at the top of my screen that says "to use dictation go to settings and turn on online speech recognition"

How can I disable this?

[image: dictation popup image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do?  If you want to use dictation in Windows and not get this message, you need to do what it says and go to settings to enable speech recognition.

Comment: It is an informational pop up. Nothing to do if you do not wish it to be enabled.